# GCP | bigquery | copy table level comments to views?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I am very new to GCP and even a high level approach to achieving  the following task is appreciated.

So currently if i want to update the view columns with description , i have to ***manually*** write the description of columns by going into console.
Is there any workaround approach where i can copy the table level comments to views automatically?